# R programming: cleaning data

Tags: r

I have a question about R programming.

If I have a dataset like the following:

```
LA NY MA
1 2 3
4 5 6
3 5
4
```

(In other words, not all rows are the same.)
I am trying to use `lm` to perform an ANOVA test (to decide whether the mean number is the same in each state), and it keeps showing "an error occurred" because rows do not match. How can I fix this issue?
Also, when I do `lm`, I usually do `lm(y~x)`, so if I want to do `lm(y~LA)`, then there's no y variable to type in. Should I create a new column/row for this?

Comment: Your data is not clear. It will help if you post first few lines of data. If it is as a dataframe, post the output of head(yourdataframe) here.

Comment: Edited the data! sorry for the confusion!

Comment: You may convert the data to a 2 column format: state and meanvalue. Then it will be easier to analyze.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Which command/package should I use to change the data to the format you said? I'm new to R..thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do something like this.  To read the data, use the `fill` argument in `read.table`.  Where `text = txt`, you would put your file name there.

```
(dat <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE, fill = TRUE))
#   LA NY MA
# 1  1  2  3
# 2  4  5  6
# 3  3  5 NA
# 4  4 NA NA
```

Then we can take the column means and create a new two column data frame.

```
cm <- colMeans(dat, na.rm = TRUE)
data.frame(state = names(cm), mean = unname(cm))
#   state mean
# 1    LA  3.0
# 2    NY  4.0
# 3    MA  4.5
```

where `txt` is

```
txt <- "LA NY MA
1 2 3
4 5 6
3 5
4"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use gather() from tidyr package to shape data into long format for the purpose of analysis. It takes multiple columns, and gathers them into key-value pairs: it makes “wide” data longer.

Sample code:

```
LA <- c(1,4,3,4)
NY <- c(4,5,6, NA)
MA <- c(3,6, NA, NA)
df <- data.frame(LA, NY, MA) # data in wide format

library(tidyr)
df <- df %>% gather(attribute, value) # data in long format
```